# How to check for updates an install new version in wpf application

Tags: wpf, version

I have developed wpf application and created the setup file.
and it's working fine, but how to check and how to install latest version over the old version programatically when click on button

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that your application is enabled to check for updates. Right-click on your *project -> Properties -> Publish tab-> updates*. Tick the checkbox *"the application should check for updates"*

[Enable check for updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKmkX.png)

Use the below code, in the button click event to check for updates

```
UpdateCheckInfo info = null;

if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

    try
    {
        info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();

    }
    catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message);
        return;
    }
    catch (InvalidDeploymentException ide)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot check for a new version of the application. The ClickOnce deployment is corrupt. Please redeploy the application and try again. Error: " + ide.Message);
        return;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
        return;
    }

    if (info.UpdateAvailable)
    {
        Boolean doUpdate = true;

        if (!info.IsUpdateRequired)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            if (!(DialogResult.OK == dr))
            {
                doUpdate = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Display a message that the app MUST reboot. Display the minimum required version.
            MessageBox.Show("This application has detected a mandatory update from your current " + 
                "version to version " + info.MinimumRequiredVersion.ToString() + 
                ". The application will now install the update and restart.", 
                "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        if (doUpdate)
        {
            try
            {
                ad.Update();
                MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
                Application.Restart();
            }
            catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into deployment using ClickOnce (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.140).aspx).  This will check for updates every time the programme is started.

In Visual Studio 2015, just hit Build -> Publish and follow the wizard.  I found it very simple.